# Allow chapters to start on an even page in front matter only

Tags: sectioning, memoir

I would like to allow chapters in my frontmatter to start on an even page, without changing the rule for the mainmatter. I've tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
%\let\cleardoublepageorig\cleardoublepage
%\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\chapter{Some Stuff}
Some text
\chapter{Preface}
Some more text
%\let\cleardoublepage\cleardoublepageorig
\mainmatter
\chapter{First regular Chapter}
And so on.
\chapter{Second regular Chapter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`memoir` provides the macro versions of `\openany`, `\openleft` and `\openright`. {See page 84, sec. 6.5 of the memoir manual).

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\openany
\chapter{Some Stuff}
Some text
\chapter{Preface}
Some more text
\mainmatter
\openright
\chapter{First regular Chapter}
And so on.
\chapter{Second regular Chapter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very clean design by memoir to provide these switching commands. Unfortunately though in my real project, in which I use the `docmute` package to `\include` the files for each of the chapters, it doesn't work yet.

Comment: A MWE using `docmute` and `\include` did produce the desired result though, so this doesn't seem to be the cause for it to fail in my real project. I'll have to look if I did any modifications to the sectioning related commands which might have caused it.

Comment: Found my problem, I still had `\frontmatter`s in the `\include`d files (in combination with manually reset page numbers).

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is for the `memoir` document class, but anyway here is the method for [the `report` and `book` classes](https://ctan.tetaneutral.net/macros/latex/base/classes.pdf) (see `\if@openright` in the documentation):

```tex
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}

% let chapters start on any page, even or odd:
\makeatletter
\@openrightfalse
\makeatother

\frontmatter
\chapter{Some Stuff}
Some text
\chapter{Preface}
Some more text

% force chapters to start on an odd page:
\makeatletter
\@openrighttrue
\makeatother

\mainmatter
\chapter{First regular Chapter}
And so on.
\chapter{Second regular Chapter}

\end{document}
```